# Page layout analysis using Tesseract?

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

[Tesseract 3](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is able to perform page layout analysis. However, I couldn't find any sample code or documentation on how to use the library for such purposes. I hope someone here can explain how to perform layout analysis on an image and how to parse the resulting data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tesseract can be given a page mode parameter (`-psm`) which can have the following values:

- `0` = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
- `1` = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
- `2` = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR
- `3` = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
- `4` = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
- `5` = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
- `6` = Assume a single uniform block of text.
- `7` = Treat the image as a single text line.
- `8` = Treat the image as a single word.
- `9` = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
- `10` = Treat the image as a single character.

Example:

```
tesseract image.tif image.txt -l eng -psm 0
```

However, I am not sure that it is possible to use the layout analysis in standalone mode.

Comment: Question is about "how to use the library", not the standalone executable.

Answer (score 5):

First, initialize `TessBaseAPI` instance. You can either use `Init()` (if you want to perform further text recognition) or `InitForAnalysePage()` (if you're interested just in text boxes).

Second, set the image using `SetImage()`.

And finally, call `AnalyseLayout()` to get `PageIterator` which provides you with text boxes.

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tessApi;
tessApi.InitForAnalysePage();

// tessApi.SetImage(...);

tesseract::PageIterator *iter = tessApi.AnalyseLayout();

// Instead of RIL_WORD you can use any other PageSegMode
while (iter->Next(tesseract::RIL_WORD)) {
    int left, top, right, bottom;

    iter->BoundingBox(
            tesseract::RIL_WORD,
            &left, &top, &right, &bottom
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an option since 3.04:

```
tesseract -c preserve_interword_spaces=1 test.tif test
```

[Here is a reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-dev/dGB3cbFtGUs/x9nEu5vy_LoJ) to what looks like the related development thread.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this exactly answers your question, but I landed here looking for ways to get the bbox-coordinates info (and text recognised inside the bbox optionally) given an input image. The solution to which is now possible using tesseract.

```
$> tesseract test.tiff test.txt -l eng -psm 1 tsv
```

The params to notice in above code-snippet are 'psm' and 'tsv'. 'psm' selects the page segmentation mode and 'tsv' generates a nice tabular output file with all the information (page-block-line number, bbox coods, confidence, predicted text) you'd need on your text-image (shown below)

```
level   page_num    block_num   par_num line_num    word_num    left    top width   height  conf    text
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   5500    4250    -1
2   1   1   0   0   0   327 285 2218    53  -1
3   1   1   1   0   0   327 285 2218    53  -1
4   1   1   1   1   0   327 285 2218    53  -1
5   1   1   1   1   1   327 285 246 38  87  INFOPAC
5   1   1   1   1   2   620 287 165 38  87  PAGE
5   1   1   1   1   3   952 290 100 37  95  NAME
5   1   1   1   1   4   1173    292 1082    45  39  ENTRYDATE
5   1   1   1   1   5   2333    302 212 36  48  EMAIL
```