# Can Tess4J handle rotated text?

Tags: java, tesseract

I am starting to play with Tess4J to see all that it can do.  From the tests I have done so far if I type text like I am doing now in a structured horizontal fashion within an image file, I can pick up the text.  If however I start to rotate the text at all, I cannot pick up the text with Tess4J.  Should Tess4J be able to handle text angled at different angles like vertical, 45 degrees and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osdetect.cpp` has some mechanism for orientation and script detection within Tesseract.  This is not brought out to Tess4J, so in this case it is better to interact with the original c++ code.  With Tesseract, one uses the psm argument (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114703/page-layout-analysis-using-tesseract) for a full list of values) for "auto-orientation".  For example, `psm -0` should provide auto-orientation.

Answer (score 4):

**Deskewing with Tess4j**

Take a look at the source code [Tess4j (Java JNA wrapper for Tesseract)](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j).

I recently posted this answer ([Java image library to deskew and crop images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273530/java-image-library-to-deskew-and-crop-images/36248013#36248013))

*Answer*:

You can combine [ImageDeskew.getSkewAngle()](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-2.0/index.html?com/recognition/software/jdeskew/ImageDeskew.html) with [ImageHelper.rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle)](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-2.0/index.html?net/sourceforge/tess4j/util/ImageHelper.html).

There is an example on how to use it on the test folder of the tess4j project [Tesseract1Test.java](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/blob/master/src/test/java/net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract1Test.java#L177)

```
public void testDoOCR_SkewedImage() throws Exception {
    logger.info("doOCR on a skewed PNG image");
    File imageFile = new File(this.testResourcesDataPath, "eurotext_deskew.png");
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    ImageDeskew id = new ImageDeskew(bi);
    double imageSkewAngle = id.getSkewAngle(); // determine skew angle
    if ((imageSkewAngle > MINIMUM_DESKEW_THRESHOLD || imageSkewAngle < -(MINIMUM_DESKEW_THRESHOLD))) {
        bi = ImageHelper.rotateImage(bi, -imageSkewAngle); // deskew image
    }

    String expResult = "The (quick) [brown] {fox} jumps!\nOver the $43,456.78 <lazy> #90 dog";
    String result = instance.doOCR(bi);
    logger.info(result);
    assertEquals(expResult, result.substring(0, expResult.length()));
}
```

[image: eurotext_deskew.png]

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Tess4J does not offer any extra functionality beyond being a simple wrapper on top of Tesseract. As such, you will have to determine the skew angle and rotate the image before OCR.

Comment: So that means if a document has text at multiple angles (like if someone scribbled handwritten text in the margins of the document) tess4j won't handle it?

Comment: Again, it depends on Tesseract engine itself. Can Tesseract handle your image?

Comment: The latest distribution of Tess4J includes helper methods that can determine the skew angle and rotate image.